# Java JLabel background color cant be changed using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I created JFrame and jLabel using NetBeans design view. I changed jLabel background color by changing background color property from Netbeans design view properties panel. But jLabel background color didn't change. Is there any other property that I should change before changing the background color of a jLabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to set opaque to true

```
yourLabel.setOpaque(true);
```

(Or tick the opaque box in the label's properties in design view in NetBeans)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. On that time you saved me from a university project @nullPointer